# Question about teaching "a couple of months" and .. to an absolute beginner

Tags: word-meaning

I bought this battery just **a couple of months** ago. I don't think I **should** have a problem with it **every second day**.

Could you please simplify the highlighted words in a very very very simple English.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 2):

My version would be:

> I bought this battery **recently**. I don't think **it** should have a problem **every other** day.

Answer (score 1):

Three *very's* means you really need effective simplification! Please mind that there cannot be *one single version* for this and others may come up with their own sentences. Having said this, this question could be marked as *opinion based*.

But, I'll give you my version

> a couple of months ago - some time ago. If you are speaking this in this month, you *might* have purchased the battery in *May or June.*
>
> ...I should have... -it is quite *obvious* that since the battery is new, it should not give any problem to you. In other words, the new battery *should* not give you any problem.
>
> ...every second day... - another way to say *more frequently*. The battery is giving problem more frequently. Again, it **should not** be the case as it's new battery.

So, a paraphrased sentence could be (my version) ...

> I don't expect this battery to give me problem. After all it's new, purchased recently.